# nginx reverse proxy with Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: nginx, cors

I want to serve fonts from our asset server. Firefox and some other browsers need to have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin set correctly and I can't get this to work.

We work in a reverse proxy. I added this to our webserver definition for the assetserver

```
location ~* \.(eot|ttf|woff)$ {
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

I also tried this

```
location ~* \.(eot|ttf|woff)$ {
   proxy_set_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

In both cases the woff and ttf files don't get the expected header in the response. I haven't been able to find any good references to get this to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you have access to the server on the command line and can do a request directly to the web server instead of going through ngix using curl -I /path/file.eot you can see if the headers are being set correctly. If they are it might be something wrong with Nginx configuration not parsing on the headers.

Comment: I'm not setting them on the source server just on the reverse proxy server. Perhaps that is the problem?

Comment: I think, I've got it working now. I also add the mime types to the nginx configuration

Comment: @Marc Can you tell us how you made it work? I also have the problem where `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is sent to the reverse proxy from the upstream server, but reverse proxy doesn't pass `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to the client.